# What is the role of content_main.xml in android studio 1.4?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I updated my android studio to latest version that is android studio1.4.

By default in a new project, there is a file `content_main.xml` in layout folder.
What is the use of this file?

Comment: Maybe it is a file of your project?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

According to new design pattern in android studio `activity_main.xml` will determine how the global UI of the Activity should be. And on the other hand `content_main.xml` will determine the contents in the `activity_main.xml`.

That is `content_main.xml` will contain the textview, edittext, button etc component. And it will be included by the `activity_main.xml`.

So we can think of `content_main.xml` just like partial in HTML. `activity_main.xml` will contain your activity global design, and `content_main.xml` will contain the contents.

From view of what they contain:

`activity_main` : Co-ordinator layout, ViewPager etc

`content_main` : Developer choosen elements. textview, edittext, button etc.

What the [android developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) says about them is

> **activity_main:**
>
> This XML layout file is for the activity you added when you created
>   the project with Android Studio. Following the New Project workflow,
>   Android Studio presents this file with both a text view and a preview
>   of the screen UI. The file contains some default interface elements
>   from the material design library, including the app bar and a floating
>   action button. It also includes a separate layout file with the main
>   content
>
> **content_main:**
>
> This XML layout file resides in `activity_my.xml` (activity_main) ,
>   and contains some settings and Textview(other) element.

Comment: So , do we have to make separate content_xxx.xml files for every layout we make?

Comment: The link is not accessible.

Comment: the link is broken and so is removed. @Akeshwar

Comment: So, is there any new documentation explaining this?

Comment: The point here being you can define co-ordinatorlayout, tablayout etc global design in activity_main and then add your elements in other xml files. just a separation to bring ease in work and more organised @RuchirBaronia

Comment: Do you have any documentation  link.@ZahanSafallwa

Comment: whatever written in developers page is included in answer also the link @RiteshMathur

Answer (score 6):

The difference between `content_main.xml` and `activity_main.xml` (for the class `MainActivity`) exists since the `API 23`. The difference between them is the following:

1. The `content_main.xml` is used for displaying the things that the
   user should see. So it contains the elements which are for the user.
   As you can see in the name, the `content_main.xml` determines the
   contents you can find in your Activity (`MainActivity` in this
   case). You use this xml-file to add new contents (`Views`) to your
   `Activity`.
2. The `activity_main.xml` has some special tasks. It contains for
   example:
        *The floatingActionButton* (the small round button you use in
   gmail for example) 
   *The tabLayout* 
   *The coordinatorLayout*
    So the
   **activity_main.xml** determines how the `Activity` (`MainActivity` in this
   case) should look. It determines its design.The **content_main.xml** is
   a part of the **activity_main.xml**.

Comment: the line `The content_main.xml is used for displaying the things that the user should see.` is totally wrong. Because user can see activity_main part too. like toolbar, floating button. `the activity_main.xml determines how the Activity (MainActivity in this case) should look.` is confusing too as activity_main only determines the global design and content_main does the part of activity specific look.