# why is there content_main.xml and activity_main.xml by default instead of just activity_main.xml?

Tags: android, xml

I have just begun learning Android App development. I have Android Studio 1.4. In my layout folder I have two XML files (`content_main.xml` and `activity_main.xml`). I use online tutorials to learn but they have only `activity_main.xml` in them. So what i want to know is what are the functions that should be used in these respective files. can i just use `activity_main.xml` and just let the other be ? and vice versa.

Comment: Have a look at the following answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32880945/5352802](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32880945/5352802)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The modern Android approach is based on `Fragments`, which are, in a way, "small Activities", which you can put in `Activities`, gaining lots of flexibility.

Therefore, `activity_main.xml` is simply the Activity layout containing a container (`FrameLayout` most probably) and `content_main.xml` is the layout for a Fragment put into this container somewhere within `MainActivity.java`. You should study the code in there to understand it better :)

Comment: So, should we use this method for each activity that we create? i.e. Create two XML files for each activity? Or is this one preferred only for MainActivity?

Answer (score 6):

As I know, there must be include statement in your `activity_main.xml` file as follows :

```
 <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

that means it is calling the `content_main.xml` which has actual elements to be hold.

There will be no problem if you cut and paste all the content of `content_main.xml` file and paste it in `activity_main.xm`l file in place of include statement(tag). 
You can delete your `content_main.xml` after doing as above.

In your activity `setContentView()` statement should be look like as below :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 3):

> According to new design pattern in android studio activity_main.xml will determine how the look of the main activity should be. And on the other hand content_main.xml will determine the contents in the activity_main.xml. That is content_main.xml will contain the textview, edittext, button etc component. And the content_main.xml will be included by the activity_main.xml .
>
> So we can think of content_main.xml just like partial in HTML.
>   activity_main.xml will contain your activity global design, and
>   content_main.xml the contents.

[What is the role of content_main.xml in android studio 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880722/what-is-the-role-of-content-main-xml-in-android-studio-1-4)

So it seems the content_main.xml is a part of a new design pattern introduced in Android Studio 1.4. 
For the moment, to get along with the tutorials you can find pick the 'empty activity' when creating a new project. It will not contain the content_main.xml.

As mentioned before, the layout file used for your activity is set with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in the `onCreate` function of the activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen Android Studio creating two layout files for one activity. Perhaps the `content_main.xml` was generated for a previous activity, wasn't it?

Anyway, it doesn't matter what is the name the layout file. Choose one and go for it. Just remember to set the right one in your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_here);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use that one which is set in Activity class. i mean set to setContentView().  or please provide your code if you want more description.