# Why Android Studio doesn't create content_main.xml every time when I create new project?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When creating new project, sometimes Android Studio creates activity_main.xml and content_main.xml, but sometimes it creates just activity_main.xml and not content_main.xml. I can't find the logic, under which condition it chooses which files to create. Can anyone explain it, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content\_main.xml missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268401/content-main-xml-missing)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new activities, you can choose different options, two of them are Blank Activity (if I recall properly) and Empty Activity. The difference between them is that one is based in the modern Android approach, based on Fragments.

Therefore, activity_main.xml is simply the Activity layout containing a container (FrameLayout most probably) and content_main.xml is the layout for a Fragment put into this container somewhere within MainActivity.java.

Answer based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33415349/6166978

Comment: I don't think content_main.xml is  binded to any Fragments by default. 
It's just "included" into activity_main.xml

Comment: An activity that has no fragment doesn't need an content_main, so it only creates activity_main