# Can't edit anything or drag widgets in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I started off with a black activity and whenever I try using Android studio, I get stuck in this screen. I cant drag any widgets, enter any text, or make any changes to the user interface. Is there anything I am missing? I downloaded all the Android Studio bundle and I have all the required SDK tools. I have attached a screenshot of what I am currently stuck with.

A screenshot of what I am seeing:

[image: A screenshot of what I am seeing:]

Answer (score 1):

Recently I encountered the same problem myself. After some research I found that you must now use the "content_activityname.xml" file in order to edit the ui of an activity.

In your case this file is located in the layout folder, right under your activity_main.xml in the picture provided.

According to this thread: [What is the role of content_main.xml in android studio 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880722/what-is-the-role-of-content-main-xml-in-android-studio-1-4) the main.xml now contains the global look of the ui, and also contains the content.xml file which again contains the components of the ui.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of uninstall and reinstall Android Studio and after that creating a new Project. You also are able to look at some tutorials created by the creators of AS. They can be found at [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com).