# Remove margin from Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-styles

I created custom Toolbar for my android app by Google's tutorial, but even thought it seems like my code is same as in tutorial, I have an addional margin at my toolbar.

[image: Margin at my toolbar]

Here is my **layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.gruber.jakub.personalscheduler.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/button1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my **styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!--Action bar style-->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
</style>
```

It only looks as I want if I change `android:padding...` property in my layout.xml, but that's not what I would like to do, because I would have to add extra properties to all others elements.

Comment: YOu are adding padding in your Relative layout. Remove that padding and it will work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take a look at your container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.gruber.jakub.personalscheduler.MainActivity">
```

You got padding all over the place! :

```
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Those are the margins. Remove them and you are fine. I suggest you start doing some tutorials.

Comment: Unfortunately, I copied it here at Stackoverflow and didn't check the content. Of course it's nonsense defining padding by margin constants. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it's good define paddings using constants. The problem it's that you've used padding in your "AcitivyLayout"... Nowadays, google recommends you separate your Acitivty layout from your content layout. In Acitivty Layout you should put your toolbar, drawer, tabs, etc. In your content, you just put your content with the paddings you have copied.

Comment: @Adley, do you maybe have some examples of that?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880722/what-is-the-role-of-content-main-xml-in-android-studio-1-4

Comment: @RobinDijkhof The code should look like this: http://pastebin.com/2WMRNJzK

Comment: Or in acitivty_main,xml instead of use RelativeLayout you can use CoordinatorLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple. Firstly, you need to remove the padding definition for your parent RelativeLayout. And since you want these properties for the rest of the view other than the toobar create a new LinearLayout/RelativeLayout and define the properties there. Like follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gruber.jakub.personalscheduler.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"   
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"      
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:text="@string/button1"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

       <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
          android:id="@+id/fab"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today"
          android:elevation="4dp" />
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```