# FindViewById from other xml layout, Android

Tags: android

I created a TextField in content_main.xml, now I can't reference it from MainActivity using findViewById, because MainActivity uses activity_main.xml.
What is the recommended way to fix this issue?

Comment: have you included `content_main.xml` in `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: Why are trying to show two different layouts in one activity ? And if you really want to show two layouts in one Activity then you have to include the second layout in your first one.

Comment: If MainActivity uses activity_main.xml, where are you using content_main.xml ?

Comment: This is clean starter project, I added a TextView to content_main.xml because I read that's the way to do it.  I'm trying to accomplish the simplest possible thing - reference the TextView and set some text. A lot of things changed since I last programmed Android and I'm a bit confused with two layouts. I'm not trying to do anything fancy here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't include content_main.xml in activity_main.xml.
The include directive is explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

A sample on include directive:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

Comment: According to follwoing answer, all insludes should already be there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880722/what-is-the-role-of-content-main-xml-in-android-studio-1-4

Comment: If you include like I wrote the views inside the content_main are all in the same tree view.
Have you assigned a unique id to the textview?

Comment: Can you post your activity_main.xml and content_main.xml?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically add layout.

inflate the layout

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.id, null);
TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_ciew_id);
```

and then add the view in parent layout

```
parent.addView(view)
```